# Zend redirector with query string

Tags: zend-framework

I want to create a redirect using a query string in `Zend 1.12`. The optional parameters should be in the form of a query string.

This is my code:

```
if ($this->_request->getParam('partner')){

   $controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
   $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
   $module = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
   $params = array(
     "utm_source" => "affiliate",
     "utm_medium" => "cpa",
     "utm_term" => $this->_request->getParam('partner'),
     "utm_campaign" => "partners",
     "url" => $this->_request->getParam('url')
   );¬

   $this->_helper->redirector($action, $controller, $module, $params);
   return false;
 }
}
```

This produces an URL like

```
/content/agb/utm_source/affiliate/utm_medium/cpa/utm_term/foo
```

However I want this to look like:

```
/content/agb?utm_source=affiliate&utm_medium=cpa&utm_term=foo
```

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had better success with building the URL myself and using `gotoUrlAndExit()`

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrlAndExit('place?thing=value');
```